# Soap Function Not Found

Tags: php, soap

So I am trying to connect using SoapClient but am running into issues.

```
$this->client = new SoapClient(self::parser_url . '/SovrenConvertAndParse/ConvertAndParse.asmx?WSDL',array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2
    ));
var_dump($this->client);
var_dump($this->client->__getFunctions());
try { var_dump($this->client->GetVersionInfo());}
catch (Exception $e){echo $e->getMessage();}
```

And here are the results I get:

```
object(SoapClient)#32 (2) {
  ["_soap_version"]=>
  int(2)
  ["sdl"]=>
  resource(42) of type (Unknown)
}

array(30) {
...
  [18]=>
  string(65) "GetVersionInfoResponse GetVersionInfo(GetVersionInfo $parameters)"
...
}

Not Found
```

Seems like if the function shows up in getFunctions() then I should be able to call it, and it should be findable. No? What could cause something like this?

So I also tried it without the try/catch and I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Not Found in /path/to/file:29
```

Anyone have any ideas as to what could be going on and how to fix this?

Comment: you need to pass the argument to the function you are calling

Comment: I tried to:
`var_dump($this->client->GetVersionInfo(array('GetVersionInfoResult'=>'xml')));`

But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm from Sovren and I just stumbled across this post. Since you didn't contact us for support I'll assume you've already resolved this problem. But for other readers, I've run the following file with PHP 5.2.12 and the call to GetVersionInfo responded correctly with both SOAP_1_1 and SOAP_1_2:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient(
    'http://localhost/SovrenConvertAndParse/ConvertAndParse.asmx?WSDL',
    array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
var_dump($client);
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
try { var_dump($client->GetVersionInfo());}
catch (Exception $e){echo $e->getMessage();}
?>
```

Comment: It turned out it was because of Soap itself. We had a port set, but SOAP seems to have issues in PHP with SOAP. We had to use a workaround which I found here: http://www.victorstanciu.ro/php-soapclient-port-bug-workaround/ Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

this should work ..

```
    $this->client = new SoapClient(self::parser_url . '/SovrenConvertAndParse/ConvertAndParse.asmx?WSDL',array("soap_version" => SOAP_1_1
    ));
var_dump($this->client);
var_dump($this->client->__getFunctions());
try { var_dump($this->client->GetVersionInfo(GetVersionInfoResult=>"version"));}  //this is where i am editing your question, you need to have a parameter passed
catch (Exception $e){echo $e->getMessage();}
```

Comment: I tried that var_dump as well, but still getting the same error. I also tried it in a different way without success (see my comment to my original post)

Comment: The 2nd var_dump (after your edit) returns the same error... I also don't see how that is any different than what I had stated before in my comment above... changing 'xml' to 'version' would not change an HTTP error... I dont think this has anything to do with the actual call, but something else.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the same code and works fine on my system. but when i changed soap_1_1 to soap_1_2 ,  I got the error message.

Comment: It could be a server issue. Thanks for the help though.